# Using custom QItemDelegate with a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qitemdelegate

I have a custom QSortFilterProxyModel to only show certain rows and columns in a table.  I also have a custom QItemDelegate to control how certain values in the table are drawn.  I'm only applying the delegate to the columns that need it and the problem seems to be that when I have the proxy model hide certain columns it messes up the delegate.

For example, suppose I have columns A-G and I apply my custom delegate to column F.

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
-------------------
o  o  o  o  o  X  o
o  o  o  o  o  X  o
o  o  o  o  o  X  o
```

If my proxy model doesn't show column B, my delegate ends up getting applied to column G instead.

```
A  C  D  E  F  G
----------------
o  o  o  o  o  X
o  o  o  o  o  X
o  o  o  o  o  X
```

I've been able to work around the problem by hiding the columns on the view instead of in the proxy model by calling

```
table->setColumnHidden(B, true);
```

And I suppose that works, but is that the only solution?  It seems like bug that the delegate and proxy model classes don't work better together, like you can use one or the other but not both on the same model very well.

Comment: As far as I know, it is working as expected: the item delegate is applied to a column of the view, which is supposed to be agnostic about the model. Additionally, your model *is* the proxy model, so it is being applied to the correct column.

Comment: I suppose you're right @cbuchart.  I guess it makes sense that when I call setItemDelegateForColumn on the view it would be the view's column I'm specifying, not the model's.  I think your proposed answer below would be a valid workaround if you know you're using a proxy model that could alter the column numbers.

Comment: You may do a qobject_cast to check if the model is a proxy model.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `mapToSource` on filtered indices (one per column) and check the original column and set the corresponding item delegate based on it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < proxy->columnCount(); ++i) {
  if (proxy->mapToSource(proxy->index(0, i)).column() == 6) {
    table->setItemDelegateForColumn(i, yourDelegate);
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, it just seems odd that I'd have to.  I would expect the view or the proxy model would automatically do that.  I'll give it a shot and if it works as expected I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a pity that it wouldn't be automatic, or at least that the model can suggest an item delegate in the same way it suggests other roles such as text alignment.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot all about this.  I think I tried this approach and it also did not work.  I ended up just calling setColumnVisible() on the view instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many good reasons not to use column position detection in display delegates.  If you let users re-arrange columns in the view, that also is a problem.  I don't think it's a bug, but I HAVE wished in the past that there was a way to assign a default delegate at the item model level.  Perhaps as a Role or something.

Anyway, one simple workaround, if you have control of the data, is to store the column/field ID right in the data itself, as a custom data role, e.g. `modelIndex.setData(FIELD_ONE, Qt::UserRole + 1)` (where `FIELD_ONE` is some enum of your columns, for example).  Then the delegate can just check that role and know what to do.